# Get data from API

Tags: angular, api

My API returns data like this: 
{"msg":"List of all sales",
"sales":[{"id":1,"user_id":3,"client_id":3,"description":"test","type":"test","status":"test","sale_date":"2020-04-01","payment_date":"2020-04-15","payment_ref":"test","total_price":"233","created_at":"2020-04-07T19:19:16.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-04-16T19:19:16.000000Z","view_sale":{"href":"api/v1/sale/1","method":"POST"},"services":[]}]}

I want to display these data in the "sales" part inside the flx-ui-datatable.
I tried like this:

```
<flx-ui-datatable
    [headers]="['Nr. i Faturës','Data e Faturës','Klienti','Përshkrimi','Shuma','Data e pagesës','Statusi']"
    [dataKeys]="['sales.id','sales.sale_date','sales.client_id','sales.description','sales.total_price','sales.payment_date','sales.status']"
    dataUrl="http://localhost/finance/server/public/api/v1/sale" 
    [hasActionButtons]="true" 
    [actionButtons]="buttons" 
    (firstActionButtonClicked)="firstButtonClicked($event)"
    (secondActionButtonClicked)="secondButtonClicked($event)"
  ></flx-ui-datatable>
```

, but this one is not working.
 Is this one : sales.id the right thing that I should do ?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this:

```
<flx-ui-datatable
    [headers]="['Nr. i Faturës','Data e Faturës','Klienti','Përshkrimi','Shuma','Data e pagesës','Statusi']"
    [dataKeys]="['id','sale_date','client_id','description','total_price','payment_date','status']", //removed sales from every key
[dataSrcKey]="'sales'" // added this thing
    dataUrl="http://localhost/finance/server/public/api/v1/sale" 
    [hasActionButtons]="true" 
    [actionButtons]="buttons" 
    (firstActionButtonClicked)="firstButtonClicked($event)"
    (secondActionButtonClicked)="secondButtonClicked($event)"
  ></flx-ui-datatable>
```

Please check this thing
as: 
**If data from api is Array ([{},{}]), Then do not specify [dataSrcKey], If data from api is JSON Object {'status':200,'data':[{},{}]} with data key holding your database records, then set [dataSrcKey] to data ;**

Above highlighted statement is from https://www.npmjs.com/package/flx-ui-datatable  which is official page of npm

Comment: Please check modified code,I have just added [dataSrcKey] and removed sales from every [dataKey] ...Please remove comments from code while inserting.

Comment: Please upvote this so others can understand it is working solution